# UITableView frame base on number of cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

As My title said that i want to set frame of `UITableView` base on number of cell. Cell's height of `UITableView` is dynamic it is not fix, for do this i apply my following logic

> **NOTE:** I added `UITableView` on `UIScrollView` so it is easy to scroll/see whole table's content. And i know `UITableView` has own scrollView but in my project i need set height of `UITableView` base on number of cell (dynamic height of cell).

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self adjustHeightOfTableview]; // custom method for set height of tableView
}

- (void)adjustHeightOfTableview
{         
    CGRect frame = self.tblView.frame;
    frame.size.height = tblHeight; // tblHeight is CGFloat, declare in .h file
    self.tblView.frame = frame;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, self.tblView.frame.origin.y + self.tblView.frame.size.height);
}
```

And get from

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);

   NSString *AnswerHeight = [[self.listOfQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Answer"]; // get 
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(queWidth - (10.0f * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [AnswerHeight sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 52);

    tblHeight = tblHeight + height + (10.0f * 2) - 1.5; // set tblHeight
    return height + (10.0f * 2) - 1.5;
}
```

But problem is that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` call 2 times so i am not able to get proper **tblHeight** so my tableView's height not set properly.

Why my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` call 2 times or How can i solve my problem ?? or any other solution for set tableView's frame base on dynamic number of cell ??

Just for understanding

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: Are you using reloadData somewhere in your code? if yes, thats the issue..

Comment: @Mr_bem - nope i doesnot  used reloadData

Comment: Then the reason is because each time you scroll the table, the visible rows will get called again.. Check my answer.

Comment: @RanjuPatel: do you have fixed starting point for table?

Comment: @preetam - sorry i can not get you..

Comment: @RanjuPatel: check my answer and let me know does it fulfil your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why to not make empty **footerView**.

```
UIView *footerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.taskListTable.tableFooterView=footerView;
```

and then change the table frame where you thinks it will change:
like in `viewWillApear` or any of your action

```
self.taskListTable.frame= CGRectMake(0,0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: Hey its working for me.. can you explain please.. what is this ?? and in my tableView i added before your suggestion `self.tblView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];` but after use your code its wrorking .. so what is difference between yours and my code ?

Comment: you have assigned the view but that view does not have any frame size...so empty frame macro is `CGRectZero`,thats all

Answer (score 1):

**heightForRowAtIndexPath** will call for each row which is going to visible.

You can calculate table height in viewDidAppear or ViewWillApearMethod.

```
for (int i =0 ; i < self.listOfQuestions.count; i++) {


NSString *AnswerHeight = [[self.listOfQuestions objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Answer"]; // get
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(queWidth - (10.0f * 2), 20000.0f);
CGSize size = [AnswerHeight sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 52);

tblHeight = tblHeight + height + (10.0f * 2) - 1.5; // set tblHeight
}
```

Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Each row will call heightForRowAtIndexPath everytime it will appear in the visible rows, so the solution is quite simple.

Create an NSMutableArray, with number of rows as your table view, then everytime you calculate the height of a row, just change that array's index for that indexPath's row with the height of that row.

And whenever you want the height of the table, just sum all your array's rows, that should do it.

If you have any more clarifications, just ask (Y)

Comment: Generally `heightForRowAtIndexPath` call for visible row but my tableView frame is larger then my number of cell so (all ros is visible when/at my table is created) so it should be call for number of cell.. i also use break point.

Comment: The behaviour isn't consistent, even if all rows are visible buddy.... If I minimized the app, or played with the table (scrolling it out of the screen), the heightForRowAtIndexPath will get called again, so I think the best way is to use the array way I just provided (Y)